# Run curl commands in parallel using xargs with inputs from csv

Tags: curl, xargs

I have a csv file with several columns including a sequence number and an image URL.  The file is 450+ lines.

```
1,text1,text2,http://image_a.jpg
2,text1,text2,http://image_b.jpg
3,text1,text2,http://image_c.jpg
.
.
.
```

The goal is to download the image at the URL with a filename being the sequence.  I accomplished this successfully with the following script

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 col4
do
   curl ${col4} > ${col1}.jpg
done < myfile.csv
```

Now I want to run the curl commands in parallel using `xargs -P`.  (I don't want to just background using `&` as I want to limit the number of processes.) I see examples using `-I` and `-R` but cannot figure out how to use multiple fields from a line of the csv file in the xargs command.

I realize gnu parallel and wget may be better options but they are not available in my unix environment.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this will help .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160/parallelize-bash-script-with-maximum-number-of-processes

Comment: passing variables .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430877/bash-xargs-passing-variable#15431066

Comment: Can you elaborate on why GNU Parallel is not available? Is it covered in: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: "they are not available" - sure, they won't be available until you install them. GNU parallel is worth to be in essentials.

Comment: I created this script for a non-technical friend to run on a Mac, so didn't want to introduce dependencies that required installing software.  Jeff's answer does the trick with the available tools.  Thanks.

Comment: @ScottNelson So if Jeff's answer had not been sufficient, then the section “My software should not depend on non-standard software” would have covered your situation? https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you'd have to build up the `curl` commands and then pass them to xargs:

```
awk -F, '{print "curl '\''" $4 "'\'' > '\''" $1".jpg'\''"}' < input.csv | xargs -P2 -I {} sh -c '{}'
```

The command looks a little ugly because I wrapped single quotes around the URL and sequence number/filenames, in case there are any shell-special characters in them (e.g. `&`).

Comment: I needed to remove the `-n1` parameter to xargs and then this works.  With that param, each token of the print was passed to sh separately.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, @Scott! I've updated the post to remove the `-n1`

Answer (score 2):

IF Scott can use one of the proposed ways to get GNU Parallel https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ then this might work:

```
parallel --colsep , 'curl {4} > {1}.jpg' :::: input.csv
```